# Grouping / clustering a list of numbers so that the min-max gap of each subset is always less than a cutoff in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, grouping, subset, cluster-analysis

Say I have a list of 50 random numbers. I want to group the numbers in a way that each subset has a min-max gap less than a cutoff 0.05. Below is my code.

```
import random

def cluster(data, cutoff):
    data.sort()
    res = []
    old_x = -10.
    for x in data:
        if abs(x - old_x) > cutoff:
            res.append([x])
        else:
            res[-1].append(x)
        old_x = x
    return res

cutoff = 0.05
data = [random.random() for _ in range(50)]
res = cluster(data, cutoff)
```

Check if all subsets have min-max gaps less than the cutoff:

```
print(all([(max(s) - min(s)) < cutoff for s in res]))
```

Output:

```
False
```

Obviously my code is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @j_random_hacker's answer, I simply change my code to

```
def cluster(data, cutoff):
    data.sort()
    res = []
    old_x = -10.
    for x in data:
        if abs(x - old_x) > cutoff:
            res.append([x])
            old_x = x
        else:
            res[-1].append(x)
    return res
```

Now it is working as expected

```
>>> print(all([(max(s) - min(s)) < cutoff for s in res]))
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only checking whether the next element is within the cutoff of the *previous* element in sorted order (that's what `old_x` is), not the least element in its cluster. So, e.g., you will output a single cluster for the input `[20, 20.03, 20.06]`.

Fix this by only updating `old_x` when you start a new cluster.

General debugging tip: Always try reproducing your problem on small instances. A good way is to start with a failing test input, and repeatedly remove elements from it until it passes. Now you know there's something special about *that* element.