# Counting elements with tolerance

Tags: python, counter

I have a long list of values (here below a shortened version) that I need to count:

```
ed = [ 0.52309  ,  3.1443  , 16.5789  , 24.0643  ,  9.70981 ,  1.71983 ,
       16.3453  , 14.1901  , 22.0353  ,  1.71983 , 15.0469  , 13.98    ,
       11.4753  , 32.7859  ,  9.7098  ,  6.36272 ,  3.2058  ,  1.46917 ,
        6.36271 , 11.5869  ,  1.72052 ,  6.32043 ,  1.72052 ,  1.72052 ,
        5.37679 ,  3.15279 ,  9.70979 ,  1.72052 ,  3.44035 ,  2.15729 ,
       12.0049  ]
```

and that I count with:

```
cnt = Counter(ed)
edlist = [list(i) for i in cnt.items()]
```

the list I obtain has some very similar values among the others

```
[[1.72052, 60], [1.71983, 34], [6.36271, 16], [9.7098, 14],[9.70979, 5], [0.52309, 3], [9.70981, 3]]
```

that I would like to add together within a given tolerance. For example

```
9.7098 has 16 counts
9.70981 has 3 counts
9.70979 has 5 counts
```

I would like to add all of them together to the item with the highest counts, and I am not sure if there is a function for that that allows to do that within some absolute or relative error. What I would like to obtain is

```
[[1.72052, 60], [1.71983, 34], [6.36271, 16], [9.7098, 22], [0.52309, 3]]
```

I have read the questions about grouping and clustering, but I do not know how to apply them. I need to count them with some given tolerance while keeping track of how many times each one has been found.

Comment: `1.72052` and `1.71983` are also close values, why aren't they added? what's the threshold?

Comment: You need grouping/clustering. Then you can pick from a large number of similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783947 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800895 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364026 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513484 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094454 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869609 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65425379 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67240666

Comment: How close is close?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I want that to be a parameter to adjust as a relative error (5%, 1%) or an absolute threshold (0.001, 0.00005)

Comment: You can use the clustering in all those links to group together values you consider similar and then count each group... How does that not answer your problem?

Comment: @Tomerikoo because if I group data what I obtain is a group of 3 elements: [9.70979, 9.7098, 9.70981], and I lose information on the total number of counts. I guess I can count the occurrence of elements in each group in the original list, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant/efficient way to do that

Comment: `len([9.70979, 9.7098, 9.70981])` is 3......

Comment: You can even save time and group after counting. You group by the key, and add the counts while doing it

Comment: @Tomerikoo exactly what I want to do, I don't know how to do neither of the 2 operations -.-"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cluster the counts according to their key, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14783980/6045800) using [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). To do that you will have to sort the list first.

Then, sum the counts of each group and add it to the final list:

```py
from itertools import groupby

l = [[1.72052, 60], [1.71983, 34], [6.36271, 16], [9.7098, 14], [9.70979, 5], [0.52309, 3], [9.70981, 3]]
l.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

tolerance = 0.001

res = []
for key, group in groupby(l, lambda x: int(x[0]*(1/tolerance))):
    # for example: key = 9709, group = [[9.70979, 5], [9.7098, 14], [9.70981, 3]]
    group = list(group)
    res.append([max(group, key=lambda x: x[1])[0], sum(x[1] for x in group)])

print(res)
```

It is mostly playing around with `lambda`s using the key or the count as the `key` to the different functions.

---

Alternatively, you could cluster the data itself (not the counts) and the count is the size of each group:

```py
from itertools import groupby

l = [0.52309, 3.1443, 16.5789, 24.0643, 9.70981, ...]
l.sort()

tolerance = 0.001

res = []
for key, group in groupby(l, lambda x: int(x*(1/tolerance))):
    res.append([key*tolerance, len(list(group))])

print(res)
```

In this case as we can't know the number with the most counts, the key is simply the normalized number according to the tolerance.

Comment: This worked perfectly after some minor edits. It is a bit of a black box to me, so I guess I need to study the lambda function to be able to exploit it

Comment: @saimon This is why I added the comment showing the "insides" of `groupby`. It can be a little confusing at the start. I suggest you to add some print lines to understand the output of the `groupby` and start with simpler 1-D lists to understand the concept. Then, the `lambda`s are just a way to tell the different functions which element to use as the indicator. i.e. the sorting is done according the first element, the grouping as well but with a calculation. The max is giving the list with the maximum second element but taking the first and the sum is of all teh second elements